# Tomcat 9 manager console not working

Tags: tomcat

I am facing issue with my Host Manager and Manager App. Currently i am not able to open my host-manager/html and manager/html. I am getting 403 error code with the status Forbidden. I google also but came with the same solution that is modification of the tomcat user but still the issue persists.I have done the same thing in my past with tomcat 6 which worked fine for me. Please let me know is anything more need to be done to fix this issue.

I have updated my tomcat-users file but still getting the same error.My tomcat user file is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jax"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

I have checked the tomcat logs nothing is there. Can anything please explain what needs to done for the same

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jax"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wan to login to the host manager, you should add "admin-gui" role:

```
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
```

And by default the Manager is only accessible from a browser running on the same machine as Tomcat. If you wish to modify this restriction, you'll need to edit the Manager's context.xml file.

- webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml
- webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml

[Tomcat guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access) says:

In addition to the password restrictions, access to the Manager web application can be restricted by the remote IP address or host by adding a RemoteAddrValve or RemoteHostValve. See valves documentation for details. Here is an example of restricting access to the localhost by IP address:

```
<Context privileged="true">
     <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
            allow="127\.0\.0\.1"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: Hi Kohie,  After adding the above role and the changes in context.xml i am still not able to access

Comment: Ummm, I can access to the manager and host manager application of Tomcat 9.0.0.M19 on CentOS 6.8 with the following tomcat-users.xm:

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
      version="1.0">
     <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
     <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
     <role rolename="admin"/>
     <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
 </tomcat-users>

Comment: I am not able to identify the reason behind this issue.Actually i am doing this on a cloud machine with a Unix machine bash

Comment: Are you accessing from localhost (from a browser of the cloud machine)? Please check logs/localhost_access_log.txt. If no, did you edit the Manager's context.xml file?